# Outlook Macro to Move entire conversations in a thread

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written a macro which should move my email conversation to my "TO DO" folder whenever I flag the email as important.  I find that the move function does happen, but I get a copy (i.e. the thread shows in both my "TODO"folder and still remains in the "Inbox".

What is also interesting is that in this line of code "For Each MailItem In Conversation.GetRootItems"  I would have expected since all the messages do get moved that MailItem>1, but in fact that bit of code only executes one time and then the loop completes.  Any thoughts on how to do a true move as opposed to be what appears to be a copy?

```
''''
Public WithEvents GExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Public WithEvents GMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set GExplorer = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer 'IGNORE THIS'
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = olFolder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
'this item/macro is used to move an email message once it has been flagged
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olInbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("DEBUG").Folders("TODO")

    Stop 'THIS WAS FOR DEBUGGING
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And Item.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked Then
        Set Conversation = Item.GetConversation

        If Not IsNull(Conversation) Then
            ' Set ItemsTable = conversation.GetTable

            'MsgBox Conversation.GetRootItems.Count

            For Each MailItem In Conversation.GetRootItems ' Items in the conversation. ONLY RUNS ONCE'
                If TypeOf MailItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
                    Item.Move olFolder
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

End Sub
''''
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the same action (`move`) is repeated for the item changed and passed as a parameter to the `ItemChange` event handler. Instead, you must run the `Move` method against the item object in the loop:

```
            For Each MailItem In Conversation.GetRootItems ' Items in the conversation. ONLY RUNS ONCE'
                If TypeOf MailItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
                    MailItem.Move olFolder
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: This makes sense and thanks, however, I think one major issue is when I call Conversation.GetRootItems the count=1 which means for some reason the code does not seem to be collecting all of the messages within a conversation.  So then the "move" loop ends up only executing one time regardless .

Comment: any thoughts on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eugene's suggestion (use `MailItem` instead of `item` when calling `Move`), you should never use `"for each`" with Outlook objects in loops that modify the collection you are iterating over - use a down loop `from Count to 1 step -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to GetChildren of the conversation.